# Error when browsing a function with flow::flow_run()

Tags: r

## Problem

I am trying to browse a function using the new `flow` package, as follows:

#### Function definition

```
library(tibble)
calculate_decc <- function(initial_DV, 
                                 initial_frspacing, 
                                 standstill_frspacing,
                                 t, 
                                 nrows,
                                 LV_acc_mps2,
                                 den){
  
  D_first <- ((initial_DV)^2) / (den * (standstill_frspacing - initial_frspacing)) + LV_acc_mps2[1]
  
  # D_reqd <- existing_decc + D_first
  
  
  
  DV <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows)
  
  DV[1] <- initial_DV
  
  
  
  D <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows)
  
  D[1] <- D_first
  
  
  
  Z <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows)
  
  Z[1] <- initial_frspacing
  
  
  
  for (i in 2:nrows) {
    
    DV[i] <- DV[i-1] + ((D[i-1] - LV_acc_mps2[i-1]) * t)
    
    Z[i] <- Z[i-1] - ((DV[i-1] * t) + (0.5 * (D[i-1]-LV_acc_mps2[i-1]) * t^2))
    
    D[i] <- ((DV[i])^2) / (den * (standstill_frspacing - Z[i])) + LV_acc_mps2[i]
    
  }
  
  return(tibble(DV, Z, D))
  
}
```

### Browsing the function using `flow`:

```
flow_run(calculate_decc(initial_DV = 25, 
                         initial_frspacing =200, 
                         standstill_frspacing=10,
                         t=1/60, 
                         nrows=1000,
                         LV_acc_mps2=vector(mode = "double", length = 1000),
                         den=2),
          , browse = TRUE)
```

### Error:

```
> flow_run(calculate_decc(initial_DV = 25, 
+                          initial_frspacing =200, 
+                          standstill_frspacing=10,
+                          t=1/60, 
+                          nrows=1000,
+                          LV_acc_mps2=vector(mode = "double", length = 1000),
+                          den=2),
+           , browse = TRUE)
Next block:  standard 
 D_first <- ((initial_DV)^2)/(den * (standstill_frspacing - initial_frspacing)) + ;    LV_acc_mps2[1];DV <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows);DV[1] <- initial_DV;D <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows);D[1] <- D_first;Z <- vector(mode = "double", length = nrows);Z[1] <- initial_frspacing 
flow_browser[1]> 
Next block:  for 
 for (i in 2:nrows) 
flow_browser[2]> 
Error: object 'DV' not found
```

## What I tried:

My function works when run outside of `flow`:

```
> calculate_decc(initial_DV = 25, 
+                          initial_frspacing =200, 
+                          standstill_frspacing=10,
+                          t=1/60, 
+                          nrows=1000,
+                          LV_acc_mps2=vector(mode = "double", length = 1000),
+                          den=2)
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
      DV     Z     D
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  25    200  -1.64
 2  25.0  200. -1.64
 3  24.9  199. -1.64
 4  24.9  199. -1.64
 5  24.9  198. -1.64
 6  24.9  198. -1.64
 7  24.8  198. -1.64
 8  24.8  197. -1.64
 9  24.8  197. -1.64
10  24.8  196. -1.64
# ... with 990 more rows
```

> What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flow::flow_run()` had a lot of problems unfortunately, sorry for that.

Please reinstall tthe package and the following should work.

```r
library(tibble)
# remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/flow")
library(flow)

flow_run(calculate_decc(initial_DV = 25, 
                        initial_frspacing =200, 
                        standstill_frspacing=10,
                        t=1/60, 
                        nrows=1000,
                        LV_acc_mps2=vector(mode = "double", length = 1000),
                        den=2), browse = TRUE)
```

It will trigger the browser inside your function's body, except that you'll notice a few `flow::update()` calls, these update silently the diagram's data.

[image: debug]

Whenever you want to draw the diagram of the current situation, call `d`, without parentheses (if `d` is overridden by a variable, use `flow_draw()` for the same effect).

[image: console]

[image: view]

Comment: This is great. Thank you for this package and yor continued improvements.